# Wevtutil to output event log description

Tags: windows, xpath, event-log

Is there anyway to only output the description field in an event log entry?

Im current using:

```
wevtutil qe Application /q:*[System[(EventID=431)]] /f:text /rd:true /c:2 /gm:true > C  :\query.txt
```

However this output everything.  I just want to output the description which is under:

```
<EventData> 
<Data> Description bllah blah</data> 
</EventData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/f:text` modifier and `grep` with `^|FIND "Description"`

wevtutil qe Application `/q:*[System[(EventID=431)]] /f:text /rd:true /c:2 /gm:true ^|FIND "Description" > C:\query.txt`

Note the `^` before the pipe, it escapes the pipe in scripts.

Comment: /gm:true doesn't appear to be a valid argument, and when I remove it all I get are single lines containing "  Description:"

Comment: I don't think /gm:true available for the "qe" command. I think the key is to not use "/f:text". In XML format, it will give you the /Event/EventData/Data element.